# Getting null when trying to select a template element in an html import

Tags: javascript, html, templates, web-component, html5-template

In my app, I do an html import from `A` to a file `B` which has this. But it alerts null. If I open `B` directly in the browser, it alerts the template HTML dom element. How can this happen, which this same code pretty much is from google own documents for web components https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/building-components/customelements.

```
<template id="x-foo-from-template">

</template>

<script>
    alert(document.querySelector('template'));
</script>
```

This is googles example:

```
<template id="x-foo-from-template">
  <style>
    p { color: orange; }
  </style>
  <p>I'm in Shadow DOM. My markup was stamped from a &lt;template&gt;.</p>
</template>

<script>
  customElements.define('x-foo-from-template', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super(); // always call super() first in the ctor.
      let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
      const t = document.querySelector('#x-foo-from-template');
      const instance = t.content.cloneNode(true);
      shadowRoot.appendChild(instance);
    }
    ...
  });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the element present in DOM when you are querying it?

Comment: if you mean the template element, i'm not sure if that counts as being in the DOM. I think the issue is, when you do an import, the document variable refers to the parent and not the current document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why does this happen?

Two factors to take into consideration when importing a file that contains a `script`, and a `template`:

1. The `script` will execute at import time, while markup and other resources need to be added to the main page explicitly

   - As pointed out in this [article on imports](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) (*by Eric Bidelman, same author as Google documentation linked in question*):

> An import link doesn't mean "*#include the content here*". It means "*parser, go off an fetch this document so I can use it later*". **While scripts execute at import time**, stylesheets, markup, and other resources need to be added to the main page explicitly.

2. A script in an import is executed **in the context of the window that contains the imported document**.  So `window.document` refers to the main page document, not the template document.

This should explain why your script alerts `null`. Because the script is executed immediately, while the template hasn't been added to the main page yet.

### How to get the desired result:

You can create a reference to the import document itself where the `template` can be found.

```
// importDoc references this import's document
var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

alert(importDoc.querySelector('template'));
```

Or, you can query the main document after you insert the template into the document:

```
var import = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
var template = import.querySelector('template');

// Append template to main document
document.head.appendChild(template);

// Now you can query the main the document
alert(document.querySelector('template'));
```

### How does Google's example differ from the example in question?

*In response to the question in the comment below:*

In Google's example, the call to `document.querySelector()` is found in the constructor function of the custom element. The constructor function is called when the element is instantiated. Therefore, the element already exists in the main page when this code is run.

Comment: So what about googles example, how come they didn't need to use `document.currentScript.ownerDocument`? Was it because from that example, all that code was in the parent document directly, and not in an html import?

Comment: @omega In Google's example, that line of code is in the constructor function of the element.  It's not executed immediately, but rather it's a callback function that is called once the element is instantiated.  So even if the example uses an import document, by the time that code gets executed, the element is already in the DOM of the main page.

Comment: But the querySelector function gets the template element, which is in the import context. Isn't it that the template element is not supposed to be in the DOM, its just supposed to be a placeholder, from which you only clone from to put in a shadowdom? Its confusing because you are making it sound like the template element is eventually supposed be put in the DOM of the parent main page, which sounds a little weird.